# Roblox Studio: CharacterAdded is not a valid member of Players

Tags: lua, roblox

I was working on a kill-logs script that would when a person dies send data over a webhook ( plr.username has died!) But, I got stuck on an error that I can't really seem to fix '' CharacterAdded is not a valid member of Players '' on the first line of the code.

What I have tried: Checking spelling to make sure nothing is miss spelled, googling/digging around dev forums.

UPDATE: Started poking around the code a bit and got a new error, still can't fix it. I would need some help pretty please.

```
--start 
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
local webhook = "removed the webhook link" -- webhook here

game.Players.PlayerAdded.
 plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character,plr)
        character:WaitForChild("Humanoid").Died:Connect(function(msg)
        local data = { --contet of data
            content = msg;
            username = plr.Name;
            avatar_url = "http://www.roblox.com/Thumbs/Avatar.ashx?x=100&y=100&Format=Png&userId="..plr.UserId
        }
        HttpService:PostAsync(webhook, HttpService:JSONEncode(data))
    end)
end)

print('nadam se da radi')

-- end
```

I can't find out how to fix this, if anybody can help me out fast I would appreciate it!

Comment: I'm starting to get sure its impossible...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a chunk of your code was accidentally deleted.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
```

If you ever get stuck on trying to use a function or signal, you can always check out the [docs online](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Player/CharacterAdded). They usually have code samples you can compare your code to.